# constructing a clojure function that returns elements

Tags: clojure

Hi im new to clojure and wanted to create a function that returns a list with three elements:

- the first element is a string
- the second element is a vector y (this should contain three keywords)
- the last element is a number

My function code so far:

```
(defn make-list [x,y,z]
    (str)
    [:y1 :y2 :y3]
    z)
```

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Please see "How to  ask a good question":   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: no all i want to ask is how to define a general function that can return me those values

Comment: it could be any arbitrary values passed to the function that returns me a list matching the above criteria

Comment: I still don't know what you mean. Please add sample inputs & outputs.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the elements that you want to build the list with are your arguments, x, y and z; and that you are going to provide the right element types (eg. `x` will be a string, `y` will be the list of 3 keywords, and `z` will be a number, you can simply call the function [list](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/list):

```
$ clj
Clojure 1.10.1
user=> (list "hello" [:a :b :c] 42)
("hello" [:a :b :c] 42)
```

In your code, what's happening is that you are providing the 3 arguments and the function is evaluating the values you passed, and the last value is simply returned:

```clj
(defn make-list [x,y,z]
    (str)          ;; this creates an empty string that is not bound to a name, will be discarded
    [:y1 :y2 :y3]  ;; this creates a vector with 3 keywords, also will be lost, same as above
    z) ;; z is the last value being evaluated, will be returned
```

like this:

```
user=> (make-list "unused" [:values :not :used :either] 99)
99
```